# replace all values in original df with updated values from new df

Tags: r, dataframe

say I have:

```
T1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E", "M")
T2 <- c("F","G","H","I","J", "K")
score1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5, 6)
score3 <- c(7,8,9,10,11, 12)
score2 <- c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)
df1 <- data.frame(T2, T1, score1, score2, score3)

T1 <- c("A","D","C","B","K")
T2 <- c("f","g","h","i","j")
score1 <- c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5)
score2 <- c(-13, -14, -15, -16, -17)
df2 <- data.frame(T1, T2, score1, score2)

> df1
  T2 T1 score1 score2 score3
1  F  A      1     13      7
2  G  B      2     14      8
3  H  C      3     15      9
4  I  D      4     16     10
5  J  E      5     17     11
6  K  M      6     18     12
> df2
  T1 T2 score1 score2
1  A  f     -1    -13
2  D  g     -2    -14
3  C  h     -3    -15
4  B  i     -4    -16
5  L  j     -5    -17
```

`df1` represents original values but then i have an updated `df2` that recorded only some of the same variables. But `df2` is more up-to-date so I want to replace all the values (for all matching columns) when `df1$T1` matches `df2$T1`.

I thought something like `df1[match(df1$T1, df2$T1),] <- df2` but it doesn't work when they are different dimensions, also it won't match along the same colnames. Joining dfs is tedious because it doesn't actually replace the values (it adds a new column like T2.y, score1.y, etc.)

I want to get something like:

```
> df1
  T2 T1 score1 score2 score3
1  f  A     -1    -13      7
2  i  B     -4    -16      8
3  h  C     -3    -15      9
4  g  D     -2    -14     10
5  J  E      5     17     11
6  K  M      6     18     12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `dplyr` `rows_update` makes this easy.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% rows_update(df2, by = 'T1', unmatched = "ignore")

#  T2 T1 score1 score2 score3
#1  f  A     -1    -13      7
#2  i  B     -4    -16      8
#3  h  C     -3    -15      9
#4  g  D     -2    -14     10
#5  J  E      5     17     11
#6  K  M      6     18     12
```

Comment: hmm, i'm getting: `Problematic argument: unmatched = "ignore" ` and if i omit it, i get `Attempting to update missing rows.`

Comment: Please check your `packageVersion('dplyr')` . I'm on `‘1.0.9’` and I do not get such message.

Comment: indeed, great function to know about! thanks, haven't worked with R in awhile

Comment: hmm, i'm running into the problem that if my original df1 has data but the df2 has NA for that value, it replaces the df1 with NA. But i'd want to keep the original value in that case. Do you know what argument to specify to keep values over NA?

Comment: I don't see any such argument in `rows_update`. I would remove the `NA` rows from `df2` so that they don't match in the first place.